# MOSFET Driver input frequency

Tags: mosfet-driver, pulse, igbt

Can I send pulse 1us (1Mhz) to [VOD3120AB Mosfet Driver](https://www.vishay.com/docs/84921/vod3120ab.pdf)?

[image]

Comment: Looks like you can, but whether the power transistor will actually switch that fast is another story, It doesn't look like you will have much duty cycle resolution even if it can.

Comment: Please define your needed output signal timing, e.g. allowed delays, distortion of duty cycle. A pulse of 1 µs duration is not the same as 1 MHz input frequency because there is a pause between pulses. What MOSFET is connected?

Comment: I'am using IRF840S (N-Mosfet) - https://www.vishay.com/docs/91071/sihf840s.pdf

Comment: Trise = 50n, Tfall = 50n, Ton = 1us, Tperiode = 1us.

Comment: OK, switching high voltages that fast is a challenge. Keep an eye on Crss and the slow body diode recovery.

Comment: Thank You for point out. Actually, I need the mosfet output voltage is only 1 volt with a current of 100mA, I limit the current and voltage by adding a resistor to VDS, and a snubber to eliminate the reverse voltage from the mosfet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can get away with it, though there will be some distortion, refer to the datasheet page 4:

[image: datasheet page 4]

You can see that they promise a "pulse width distortion" of 5 to 70 ns, however they also indicate that the propagation delay difference could be up to +/- 100ns. You will get at least 90% of your pulse and no more than 110%, in my understanding.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Do you have a recommended mosfet driver that fits my needs for a 1us pulse input?

Comment: @Ihdina technically component recommendations are against the rules here, but also no: I’ve never had to go that fast. I’d be inclined to try this driver though - it seems reasonable and you can always monitor the output and self calibrate.

Comment: Thanks for the point out, I'll do that first.